# Triggering Backbone.js event via table html

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following html view template which contains a table:

```
<script id="user-home-main-table-template" type="text/template">

    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Delete?</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <% for(var i=0; i
    <teams.length
            ; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%= teams[i]._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                    <%= teams[i].club %>
                </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%= teams[i]._id%>/deleteTeam'>
                    delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

I want to change it so that it triggers an event in event in Backbone instead of just making a request straight to the server:

```
<script id="user-home-main-table-template" type="text/template">

    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Delete?</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <% for(var i=0; i
    <teams.length
            ; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%= teams[i]._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                    <%= teams[i].club %>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href='make a request to Backbone when deleting team'>
                    delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

here is my Backbone view code:

```
var UserHomeMainTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    events: {},
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind();
    },
    render: function () {
        var userHomeMainTableTemplate = document.getElementById('user-home-main-table-template').innerHTML;
        this.$el.html(_.template(userHomeMainTableTemplate)());
        console.log('userHomeMainTableTemplate rendered');
        return this;
    }
});
```

how do I trigger an event in my Backbone view that pertains to the team with the right id? I need to send Backbone the id of the team to delete.

Comment: What is the `this.bind()` for in `initialize`?

Comment: hey Mu, I don't know what the bind is for perpahps it's extraneous code

Comment: It doesn't do anything so I'd get rid of it.

Comment: alright that I can do

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserHomeMainTableView's` `events` hash, you can add `click <your_element_selector>` property with a value as `eventHandlerName` for e.g.

```
var UserHomeMainTableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    events: {
     'click .table span' : 'deleteTeamById'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind();
    },
    render: function () {
        var userHomeMainTableTemplate = document.getElementById('user-home-main-table-template').innerHTML;
        this.$el.html(_.template(userHomeMainTableTemplate)());
        console.log('userHomeMainTableTemplate rendered');
        return this;
    },
    deleteTeamById: function (event) {
        //using event fetch the target from that fetch team or user id whatever                  you need, make sure you add it as an attribute in template and use it
        var teamId = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-team-id');
        //Your logic to delete team
    }
});
```

Template can be changed to :

```
<script id="user-home-main-table-template" type="text/template">

    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Delete?</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <% for(var i=0; i
    <teams.length
            ; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href='/users/<%=user._id%>/teams/<%= teams[i]._id%>/teamDashboard'>
                    <%= teams[i].club %>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-team-id="<%= teams[i]._id%>">
                    delete
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
</script>
```

Have a look at [this](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#views-1) examples.